# How do I retrieve data from firebase database Storage and displaying it into custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I find difficult to display my communities node in ListView.
This is my tree in Firebase :
[My Firebase tree](https://screenshots.firefox.com/yveMILeFIHKmyf0Q/console.firebase.google.com)

I would like to display in ListView in Android List of three items containing the three community (community1, 2 , 3) with their details MessageSentCount, MessageReceivedCount.

I'm newbie in Android also in Firebase, I followed many tutorials and while trying the application crashes
My class :

```
    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_analyze);

    listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clusters");
    dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

My layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_discover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/button_discover"
        android:onClick="discoverYourself"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have checked many tutorials but haven't find the solution. Kindly help me out.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- hi , please try to add Log message when child added

  ```
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
             String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
             Log.e("value",value)
             list.add(value);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
  ```

  to be sure that there is some child and the problem is on your
  listview
- then try to change : `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` by `adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1);`
- also try to change this on your xml : `android:layout_height="0dip"` by : `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

**to fix converting exception:**

```
dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clusters/Community");
dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
int messagesSentCount = dataSnapshot.child("messagesSentCount").getValue(Integer.class);
list.add(name);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: for this 
adapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size()-1); it dosent work!
and  I had the same error! 
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: @XYZW i changed the response , try now !

Comment: use   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , it's okay